# MAC Address of WiFi access point of a Mobile Device (android/IOS) through mobile web browser (html5/javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to access WiFi information of my Mobile phone (BSSID specifically) through the web browser on my mobile phone (using any browser side languages - Html 5/Javascript etc)?